# git hunk edit mode - how to remove a '-' line?

Tags: git, patch

```
+ bbb
- aaa

# ---
# To remove '-' lines, make them ' ' lines (context).
# To remove '+' lines, delete them.
# Lines starting with # will be removed.
#
# If the patch applies cleanly, the edited hunk will immediately be
# marked for staging. If it does not apply cleanly, you will be given
# an opportunity to edit again. If all lines of the hunk are removed,
# then the edit is aborted and the hunk is left unchanged.
```

I simply don't understand what `make them ' ' lines` means. How to apply `+ bbb` only but not `- aaa`?

Comment: It's definitely bad wording, "line" is wrong and confusing.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

`make them ' ' lines` means you need to replace the `-` in front of the line with a  (space).

Comment: To add to that, if editing with `vim` and you wish to mass-replace across multiple lines, e.g., 7-200, the following command would do: `:7,200s/^-/ /`. This regex searches for a single `-` at the beginning of each line within the specified range and replaces it with a single space.

Comment: Awesome I have no idea what to do until seen this answer. Thanks

Comment: Note for future self: replace **only** the `-` but keep the rest of the line

Answer (score 31):

A hunk like this:

```
+ bbb <-- line added
- aaa <-- line deleted
  ccc <-- line unchanged
```

will turn into content like this:

```
bbb
ccc
```

To keep a line marked for deletion (prefixed with `'-'`), turn it into a line with the same prefix as the `unchanged` line above (so it will stay the same):

```
+ bbb
  aaa
  ccc
```

When the hunk is applied, the contents will look like this:

```
bbb
aaa
ccc
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the clearest explanation I've found.