# How to to selectively edit and accept changes committed in another branch without editing hunks?

Tags: git

I am trying to select/edit changes from another branch before merging -
e.g., after a fetch.

When there are conflicts, it is easy to go to a conflicted file and 
remove/edit the text between '>>>' and '<<<'.
But when there is no conflict it seems that the usual way is to edit hunks like I have found in some answers [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367645/git-how-to-selectively-apply-changes-from-one-branch-to-another), [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333828/how-to-edit-git-add-patch-hunks-diffs-lines-during-selective-staging):

```
git checkout -p
```

or

```
git add -p
```

However, despite the simplicity of the hunk [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731269/git-hunk-edit-mode-how-to-remove-a-line), a single (after splitting) long hunk sometimes is not practical to be correctly edited. I suppose the difficulty comes when the [number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268596/git-add-interactive-your-edited-hunk-does-not-apply) of lines changes  or ' ' lines are unwittingly removed or transformed into '+' lines.
Another problem, maybe even more important, is that the whole file is not available. There are text gaps between hunks that otherwise could make editing more comfortable.

**One solution I think of is to simulate all changes as conflicts.
Is that possible?**
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935226/git-interactive-merge) suggests a complex sequence of commands with a comment suggesting a equally complex (to be used at git root) alias:

```
git config --global alias.remerge '!sh -c "git show HEAD:${2} > ${2}.HEAD; git show ${1}:${2} > ${2}.${1}; git show $(git merge-base HEAD ${1}):${2} > ${2}; $(git config --get merge.tool) ${2}.HEAD ${2} ${2}.${1};"'
```

Another answer for the same question presents the least confusing  solution that is to *check out the other branch in a different working copy*, which weirdly remembers me of my SVN remote past.

**None of the solutions seems adequate to be performed on a routinely basis.**

[An example of scenario is when I receive code or text files from someone that is supposed to perform approximate contributions, that need corrections regularly. A more concrete case could be a software spec or even code or a scientific paper being fetched from a software architect or a supervisor after his/her fast-and-dirty review.]

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just add another commit to that branch with the changes you want, then merge?

Comment: Because I want to be able to edit the _changes_ to be made to the file, not the _changed_ file. E.g., If the other person deletes lines, they simply do not appear on the file; so I could not know that without resorting to a diff (git diff). The problem is resorting to a diff for every change. The hunk editor is half way to solve this, but I hope there is a more practical solution.